# Representing a never ending binary number

Tags: ieee-754

I was reading that on February 25, 1991, during the Gulf War, an American Patriot Missile battery in Dhahran, Saudi Arabia, failed to intercept an incoming Iraqi Scud missile. The reason was that 1/10 was represented in 24 bits.(1/10 is a never ending binary number). I wanted to know how do we represent such a number in say 32 bits or 64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.1 decimal is an infinite (repeating) fraction in binary: 0.0(0011), where () indicates the repeating part. Here it is, truncated after 80 fractional bits (I used my [binary converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/) to produce this):

0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001...

Rounded to 24 *significant* bits (float) it's 0.000110011001100110011001101 . Rounded to 53 *significant* bits (double) it's 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101 .

Comment: @Akito: The binary converter that I wrote -- that's on my Web site.

Comment: @Akito: Yes, truncation will introduce an error. But the bits are correct to the point of truncation.